Find Contacts Menu Item Does Not Work
I have recently moved my database from WordPress to Drupal. All of the menu items I have looked at and most everything else on the site are working correctly except the Findact Contacts menu item in the Search menu.

Clicking the menu item goes to https://site.org/civicrm/admin/ui%3Acontact%3Asearch
which brings up an admin screen.

I have gone to site.org/civicrm/dashboard?reset=1 and this did not resolve the problem.
I am running CiviCRM 5.70.1.
The search functions accessed in other parts of the site appear to working correctly. I would like users of this site to be able to use this function if possible.  Any ideas on how to solve this are greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
Steve

Seems to be related to the adminui (preview) core extension being installed, and it only affected some of our CiviCRM installations.
In the db civicrm_navigation table, menu id = 3 had url civicrm/adminui/contact/search
Changing it back to civicrm/contact/search?reset=1 and rebuilding the menu (/civicrm/menu/rebuild?reset=1) fixed the issue.
UPDATE `civicrm_navigation` SET `url` = 'civicrm/contact/search?reset=1' WHERE `id` = '3'; 

